# Nginx failover no load balancing only if fail

Tags: nginx, failover, failovercluster

Hi i'm using nignx for reverse porxy. I just want to send my all requests to my first server. But if the first server is down, I want to send requests to second one.

I have tried that:

```
    upstream backend {
        server 1.1.1.1 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=5s;
        server 1.2.2.2 backup;
    }

    server {
        listen  80;
        server_name example.com;

    location / {
            proxy_pass              http://backend;
    }
    }
```

Seems my nginx can't understand the "backup" string
My version: 1.8.0

Comment: try to remove max_fails and fail_timeout it should work